# How can i shorten this PHP code? (if - elseif)

Tags: php

I have this simple if else function and i wonder how i could shorten this?

```
<?php 
    if( $count_bananas == '1' )
    { echo '<div class="stage-columns-1">'; }

    elseif ($count_bananas == '2') 
    { echo '<div class="stage-columns-2">'; }

    elseif ($count_bananas == '3') 
    { echo '<div class="stage-columns-3">'; }

    elseif ($count_bananas == '4') 
    { echo '<div class="stage-columns-4">'; }
?>
```

The code works but i wonder if there is a way to code this shorter and more elegant?

Comment: use ternary operator :)

Comment: May be multiple ternary operate can help you

Comment: @Insomania a ternary operator would make a big mess for future debugging

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really didn't see the pattern?

```
echo '<div class="stage-columns-' . $count_bananas . '">';
```

Comment: better than perfect :)

Comment: okay i am a php beginner but i should have seen it, thx a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

It can be done without condition checks. For the code snippet you are posted, if the values are same then -

```
echo '<div class="stage-columns-' . $count_bananas . '">';
```